# Корень в слове "чморить"

Tags: корень-слова

Какой корень в слове "чморить"?

Comment: По-моему, чаще используют "чмырить", но даже если "чморить", то очевидно корень "чмор", какие тут могут быть вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Этот глагол происходит от существительного "чмо", которое, по некоторым данным, является аббревиатурой – человек морально опущенный. Следовательно, эти три буквы и есть корень.

Comment: про «человека морально опущенного» похоже на народную выдумку. это как с ПТУ — «помоги тупому устроиться». думаю, слово «чмырь» может иметь этимологическое сходство со словом «хмырь». значения у них примерно одинаковые, произношение тоже. но чмырь (явно однокоренное с «чмо») употребляется больше в тюремной среде. и возможно, что «чмырь» появился раньше, чем «чмо».

Comment: Хмырь - это слуга в тюремной среде, а чмо - это грязнуля, тот, кто совершенно за собой не следит, живя только инстинктоми. Это кординально разные понятия.

Comment: Есть даже такое понятие, как хмырня.

Comment: не согласна с вами по поводу значения слова «чмо». в общераспространенном употреблении это униженный человек, ущемленный и никчемный. пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на источник, где говорится, что оно обозначает того, кто не следит за собой.

По поводу «хмыря»: Ефремова и Ожегов определяют его как неприятного, опустившегося человека. И даже в словаре русского арго значение такое же. То есть сходство между «чмом(чмырем)» и «хмырем» налицо.

Comment: Я был связан непосредственно с исправительными учреждениями, где по поводу этих понятий ни у кого не возникает сомнений. Они часть повседневной жизни тамошних обитателей: как осуждённых, так и их охраны. Возможно у Пикуля можно что-то отыскать(это я про источники), либо в детективах 90х, кои я не читаю. Мои интересы - история и археология.

Answer (score 0):

Сленг - это слова оторванные от этимологии, например, через создание литерных сокращений, которые тоже называют аббревиатурами, хотя это слова образованные не через сращение корней, как кол-хоз, а, скажем, по заглавным буквам, причем часто это вербализированное произнесение букв, которое может не совпадать с оригинальными заглавными буквами в словах. То есть пока известно, от какой аббревиатуры произошло слово - еще кое-как можно связать его с некоторым характерным набором слов, не фразы, а именно специфично расставленных слов, так как эти слова уже вырваны из контекста. Кроме того сленг может быть образован через нехарактерное обрубание корня.

Поэтому, скорее всего, чмо - это человек морально опущенный, словечко проскакивает в литературе после 1970-хх. Было еще, например, "бич" - бывший интеллигентный человек, "лох" - лицо обманутое хулиганами. С бичом вопросов обычно не возникает, а вот лох пытаются возводить к солохе, которая связана скорее всего с салом, чем-то липким и неприятным, но тогда где корень сол? обрублен. В любом случае лох - нетипичный обрубец, а далее можно спорить конечно, но зачем?

Причины сленга в шифровании языка, сленг - не жаргон, жаргонные морфемы не выпадают из логики этимологического корня, а сленг вообще теряет с ним всякую связь. Заключенным требуется шифроваться, чтобы их не запалили легавые, поэтому у них вырабатывается специфический язык - причина, не удобство употребления специализированной речи, а попытка избежать ответа за базар.

Потом были другие называния - битник, от английского бит - нехарактерного корня для русского языка, образована через вербализацию слова beat, произнесение вслух, а не семантический перевод, был бы русский корень бить, был бы бьющий. Или, например, слово Jeep-Джип - которое есть произнесение литерной аббревиатуры GP - general purpose(общего назначения, военный термин, в смысле военная техника не специального, а военного и гражданского одновременно - общего, автомобиль универсального класса) автомобиль, изначально военной разработки ставший  после гражданским брендом.

Или слово чувак и ряд других - которые возводят к вербализации английского слова chewing, жующий наркотик, насвай например:

> Если ты, чувак, индеец,
>
> Ты найдёшь себе оттяг… Ф. Чистяков

Кстати, эта прекрасная история про чувака основательно существует на педивикии, казалось бы, причем тут она? Или битник:

Джек Керуак, Аллен Гинзберг и круг их ближайших друзей были одними из тех, кто создавал возрождающуюся богему из движения хипстеров — которое спустя некоторое время трансформировалось в битничество.

Поразительно, но статьи о сленге написаны на -вики с такой нежностью и любовью, я бы никогда не узнал значения этих слов без неё. Потому что своё, потому целая статья посвященное сленговому слову как культурному объекту, чего не скажешь об остальных словах и понятиях уже русского языка. Сленг - это вид словообразования имеющий отношение к англосаксонской культуре.

Сленг - это явление характерное для криминальной, либо для военно-разведывательной среды, и это явление связано с шифрованием человеческого языка. Так что какого-то большего смысла, чем характеризующий ЗЕКа набор слов, мне кажется в сленговом ЧМО нет и зачем?

Вообще сленг, ввиду потери или отсутствия какого-либо морального значения, употребляется только в специфическом или негативном ключе. Забывается происхождение слова, и слово используется для ругани - то произнесением звуков с мышлением не связанным. Например слова дебил, идиот - теряют какие-либо смыслы и употребляются только для брани или в негативной коннотации.

Вот, например, прочитал только что:

> Среди единичных вариантов ответов под рубрикой «Другое» встречались отправка [дикпиков](https://www.rbc.ru/economics/20/07/2023/64b7e2e29a79477fbf65e4c1?from=from_main_2) (фото половых органов)

Такая вот эвфемизация, "хорошо" расшифровка есть, и понятно о чем речь, ну и хорошо морфемы остались, а могли бы быть и "дипишки". Хотя, чем больше узнаю про сленг, ощущение, что это какая-то [тупиковая ветвь эволюции](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/80765805#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%0A%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5.%20%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%22%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%22%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5.) языка. То есть отомрёт, конечно, само, но когда время придет, как только условия будут менее щадящими к бессмысленному повторению оного и когда людям понадобятся слова несущие смысл - язык для общения, а не только для коммуникации. Когда люди начнут думать, что говорят, и говорить, что думают, а не юзать язык шифруясь и скрывая свои истинные намерения.

А чморить - это сленговое образование от морфы "чмо", но корня у него нет, потому что это слово не имеет этимологии, а является набором литер от слов "морально опущенный человек", используемое для негативной характеристики персонажа, например, в тюремной среде. Чморить, значит - морально(словесно, а не физически, скорее оказывая психологическое давление) унижать кого-то, издеваться над кем-то, часто группой, ввиду морального превосходства группы. Указывать новоприбывшему на его низкое положение в групповой иерархии, низкую социально значимую роль.

> ― Таких лохов надо сразу [чморить](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClIqLAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKLji3%2BDgm9MPMglncmNyZWF0ZWRABWoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBAUIbChkKFwoDcmVxEhAKDtGH0LzQvtGA0LjRgtGMMAE=#:%7E:text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%20(2000)-,%E2%80%95%20%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%20%D1%87%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C.,-%E2%80%95%20%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2), пока они не возомнили о себе, что они, мол, подмосковные Аль Капоне, туды ее в качель.